GraphQL Upload Value Invalid Error When Uploading Images from React Native Using Apollo Client and react-native-image-picker
I'm currently working on a React Native application where I need to upload images to my GraphQL server using Apollo Client and react-native-image-picker. However, I'm encountering an issue where I consistently receive an "Upload value invalid" error from the server when attempting to upload the image.

I've verified that the file object is constructed correctly with the appropriate URI, type, and name properties.
The MIME type (type property) of the file object is set to image/jpeg or image/png based on the selected image.
My GraphQL server is configured to accept file uploads, and the server-side mutation handling the file upload appears to be correctly implemented.
I've tested with static files and encountered the same error, ruling out issues with the file selection process.


const handleImage = async () => {
    const options: ImageLibraryOptions = {
      mediaType: 'photo',// Limit selection to one image
    };

    launchImageLibrary(options, (response: any) => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('user cancel the image pikker');
        return;
      } else if (response.errorCode) {
        console.log(response.errorMessage);
        return;
      }

      console.log('image ', response?.assets);`your text`
    
      if (response.assets) {
        const file = {
          uri: response.assets[0].uri,
          type: response.assets[0].type || 'image/jpeg', // Default to JPEG if type is not provided
          name: response.assets[0].fileName || 'image.jpg', 
        }
        setProfile(file);
      }
    });
  };


calling the api
        variables: {
          email: route?.params ? route.params.data.email : email,
          fullname: name,
          password: route.params?.data?.password,
          nikname: nikname,
          image :profile
          
        },
      });

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: `${env.server}/graphql`,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: createUploadLink({
    uri: `${env.server}/graphql`,
    headers: {
      'apollo-require-preflight': 'true',
    },
  })
});

